# Best practice for integrating a single PayPal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm new to PayPal and overwhelmed by all the possible approaches for integrating with PayPal.
As a start I want to implement one single subscription with monthly recurring payment. When the user returns to the site after fulfilling the payment, he/she will *instantly* be upgraded to "premium" member (digital product only - no shipping involved).

The first alternative I've looked into is the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/), which looks ok, but is there any simpler way to do it?

Can I for example create a standard button (JS button or the form based), but still be able to verify the payment details when the user returns, using either the REST API, IPN or something else?

Any hints on best practices are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are entirely too many ways to solve this problem by now.

You can probably satisfy your requirements via buttons (aka Standard), Express Checkout (aka Pro) style APIs, or RESTful APIs, but there are a few gotchas to know:

First, PayPal has several products to do recurring payments; these products have *functional differences* and are tied to different *integration styles*. So (for example) PayPal's product called "subscriptions" (tied to Website Standard aka buttons) has different (and generally less flexible) capabilities than "recurring payments" (tied to Express Checkout) which in turn differs from "billing agreements" (tied to REST APIs, although the term "billing agreements" is also used in the express checkout recurring payments product). Oh, and there's another similar product tied to the Adaptive Payments suite of APIs.

Confused yet? Sorry. But it is important to determine whether the specific product you want to use will satisfy your requirements first before you do any integration, or you might end up redoing that integration work later (and potentially have to migrate customers, if you have already opened your business) in order to get access to specific features of another product later on. E.g., the subscriptions product has very limited ability for sellers to modify the subscriptions after they are set up. If that is OK, then great, use it -- it's simple to integrate. If I can oversimplify a bit: the Standard subscriptions product is the oldest and most limited; the Pro recurring payments is more flexible and mature; the REST billing agreement product is the newest, very flexible, but not yet as widely used; it may lack a feature you need *today*, but is the most likely to be continually improved going forward. I would not personally recommend the Adaptive product, although it also has its benefits.

Now, to your integration question: fortunately all these PayPal products can use IPNs. Unfortunately, IPNs are *not* instant. They generally arrive quickly (1-2 seconds) but delays *can* happen and it is quite awkward to be unable to process the customer. I would use IPNs only when shipping physical goods, not for immediate access to digital goods or in other cases where customers are waiting for a page from you. Fortunately, each of the other methods has a way to instantly determine the success of a PayPal action without waiting for an IPN:

Website Standard Payments will include GET or POST variables when it posts the user back to your site that will tell you about the outcome. If you use the Payment Data Transfer feature, these variables will include signature information so that you can post them *back* to PayPal & PayPal will verify their validity (so that a would-be thief could not fool you by engineering a post that looks like a PayPal success redirect).

The two API-based methods are even easier: the APIs themselves return all the information you need in the API response. So wherever in your code you make the call to create the subscription/agreement, if you get back a success then do your work to make your user premium.

There is the odd case of a user successfully paying and then getting "lost", as it were, e.g. the redirect failing/browser closing before they return to your site, or your site choking while trying to turn on the user. For this reason many people advise using IPNs, which PayPal will attempt to redeliver until you verify them back to PayPal. Not a bad idea, depending.

And of course you can call search & get details type APIs to get information about your transactions & agreements at PayPal -- although again, you will need to integrate with the right API that matches the product you are integrated with (e.g. Standard-based subscriptions won't show up if you ask the REST interface for billing agreements).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Geewiz, thanks for this detailed answer.  I am currently building an e-commerce platform single page application and I am wondering if it is "secure" enough if I use the paypal js client for the payment and on successful callback register an order for the logged in user via the wordpress rest API? Would I have to validate this purchase again in the WC backend or do you have any other recommendations how to proceed here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm years out of date now, and don't know the wordpress rest API at all. I don't think I can help you. Good luck!